# Unterschiedliche Artikel für "Match?"

Tags: meaning, article, grammatical-person

Es gibt ja mehrere Bedeutungen des Wortes Match. Haben die aber auch alle den gleichen Artikel?

- Das Tennismatch im Sinne des sportlichen Wettkampfes, wo der Artikel "das" ist, ist wohl am Bekanntesten.
- Den Match in der EDV im Sinne von Treffer, wo ich zwar intuitiv "der" schreibe, aber nicht weiß, ob es richtig ist.
- Match im Sinne von Abgleich - auch aus der EDV/IT bzw. Bankgewerbe - wenn ich zum Beispiel zwei Datensätze miteinander "matche", dann werden Sie miteinander abgeglichen. Auch diesem Match würde ich intuitiv "der" voranstellen, aber liege ich damit richtig?

Laut meinen Recherchen hat die dritte von mir aufgezählte Bedeutung des Wortes es auch nicht in den Duden geschafft. Dort stehen die Artikel "der" und "das" aber ohne nähere Erläuterung oder Zuordnung.

Comment: Der Einwand ist berechtigt. Den Thread habe ich bisher nicht wahrgenommen.

Comment: Ich sehen keinen wirklichen Unterschied zwischen den Punkten 2 und 3. In beiden Fällen werden Dinge miteinander verglichen und wenn was passendes gefunden wird gibt es einen Match.

Comment: @raznagul: Ich sehe den Unterschied auch nicht, aber ich wollte wissen, ob ich mich hier auf meine Intuition verlassen und die ggf. auch durchsetzen kann. Der andere Thread, den ich zwischenzeitlich durchgelesen habe, bestärkt uns beide.

Comment: Im Schweizerischen Hochdeutsch heißt das Fußballspiel übrigens "der Match" und die IT-Bedeutung dürfte eher EDV-Slang als anerkanntes Deutsch sein - die Wörterbücher kennen die Bedeutung als "Fundstelle" oder "Gleichheit" größtenteils (noch) nicht.

Comment: Richtig. Das mit dem EDV-Slang zeigt sich auch besonders in dem Wort GUI (Grafical User Interface), welches konsequenterweise eigentlich das GUI heißen müsste, sich aber trotzdema ls die GUI durchgesetzt hat.

Comment: Wieso muss 'das GUI' heißen? Beim sportlichen Match - treffen da nicht auch zwei Mannschaften aufeinander, passenderweise in der gleichen Sportart? Dass die Schweizer 'der Match' sagen beweist, glaube ich, wenig, weil deren Artikel oft von denen anderer Deutschsprachler abweichen. Sagen die nicht auch der oder das Butter?

Comment: Ich leitete den Artikel von GUI vom Interface ab. Das Interface.

Comment: Ich würde sowohl beim ersten als auch beim zweiten Beispiel stets _das Match_ sagen. Im dritten Beispiel müsste der Abgleich _das Matching_ heißen, denn es geht ja um den Vorgang, und nicht um das, was abgeglichen oder getroffen (der Treffer) wurde.